# Infinite While Loop and Getting Incorrect Output

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I am currently trying to build a program that reads in a file,      scans through that file, and outputs all words in that file surrounded by " marks. I am currently stumped and was hoping to get some help!

```
#include <iostream>
// For file I/O:
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// Prototype the count function so we can have it below it's first
// use in main().
void count(istream& in, int& lines, int& words, int& characters);
/*
 * wc <filename>
  */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 if (argc < 2) {
   cerr << "Usage: wc <filename>" << endl;
  return 0;
 }
 // Open the file specified by argv[1] for reading:
  // Constructs a ifstream object called "in":
  ifstream in(argv[1]);
  // Was there a problem opening the file?
  if (!in.good()) {
   cerr << "Unable to open file [" << argv[1] << "] for reading." << endl;
   return 1;
  }

   int lines = 0, words = 0, characters = 0;
  count(in, lines, words, characters);
   cout << setw(5) << lines << " " << words << " " <<
    characters << " " <<           argv[1] << endl; 

  // Close the input stream:
  in.close();
   }

   void count(istream& in, int& lines, int& words, int& characters) 
   {
   int i;
   char s;
   int ch;
   bool inword = false;

  // Read until the end of file is reached, or there was an error:
  while (!in.eof()) {
   // Read a character from the input stream "in":
    s = in.get(); //Set char s = in.get
     for(i=0; s != 0; i++){ //Loop to iterate through the characters
      while(s == '"'){ //While s is equal "
       cout << s << endl; // Print s
        if(s == '"') // If we hit another ", then we break
        break;
      }
    }
    if (in.good() == false) return;
   characters++;
   if (!isspace(ch) && !inword) {
    inword = true;
    words++;
    } else if (isspace(ch) && inword) {
     inword = false;
    }
    if (ch == '\n') lines++;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your algorithm seems wrong.. in the for loop you compare to 's' but you're not updating it... try something like this in your main loop(QnD):

```
while (!in.eof() && (s = in.get()) != '"'); // read to first quote char
/* this is the word we want.. run to end quote marks.. */
while (!in.eof() && (s = in.get()) != '"') {
    cout << s;
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: I did that but I seem to still be infinitely looping. It also isn't printing anything, it seems to just be cout-ing endl.

Comment: Ignore that last comment, I figured out why it was infinitely looping. I am now getting seg faults.. Any comments on why this could be?